# Sequelize - simple update not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need to update one value in one row in my PostgreSQL DB through a simple Model.update() call.

It has always worked easily, but after updating to sequelize v4 it only updates column updatedAt (that's whats in logs), nothing more.

My code:

```
const updatedRow = await MyModel.update(
  {name_of_column: "NEW VALUE"}, 
  {
    where: { id: SOME_ID_NUMBER },
    raw: true,
    returning: true,
  }
);
```

I tried all possible combinations of properties raw/returning, even fields and attributes, but nothing is working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this is it, but try switching `raw: true,` for `plain: true`.

The below comes from the [upgrade to v4 docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html).

"Getters wont run with `instance.get({ raw: true })`, use `instance.get({ plain: true })`"